# DriveInfo does not exist in current context?

Tags: c#, linq, driver

Why do I get the following error on the C# LINQ code below

`DriveInfo does not exist in current context`?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
             .Where(drive => drive.IsReady && drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable);
        }
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `using` directive:

```
using System.IO;
```

... to import [`System.IO.DriveInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx).